# Adding the intersections of circles.

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Given the grid attached, how can you place the numbers $1-20$ at the intersections so that each circle adds to the same sum. I haven't been able to figure this out.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are ten pairs of circles. Each pair meets in two points.  If you make each matching pair sum to $21$ you will be done.  Each circle goes through four pairs, so the sum will be $84$.  Thinking about the symmetries of the problem is often a good place to start with these problems.